# GitHub packages + actions automation for NuGet package

Tags: github-actions, github-packages

We're looking for the ability to publish a new version of a GitHub package (auto bumping the NuGet `PackageVersion` value in the csproj file) on PR merge. We would like this to bump the version based on a tag added to the PR. We have this working in parts but getting it all seamlessly tied together is proving confusing. I'm very surprised GitHub does not have anything like this available out of the box.

First we require PR labels on PRs. This is in hopes that we can bump the correct version number in the next pipeline.

```
name: Require PR Labels

on:
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, labeled, unlabeled, synchronize]

jobs:
  require_label:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: mheap/github-action-required-labels@v2
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        with:
          mode: exactly
          count: 1
          labels: "release:major, release:minor, release:patch, no release"
```

Then when a merge is detected (src only) we want to bump the .csproj NuGet PackageVersion based on which label was added.

```
0.0.1.0 for patch
0.1.0.0 for minor
1.0.0.0 for major
```

**Right now this step always updates the 3rd node of the version. We'd like for a way to identify that the last PR merged had a certain tag on it and define which version_mask to use based on that tag**

```
name: Bump NuGet Package Version

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
    paths:
      - 'src/**'

jobs:
  version-bump:
    name: bump nuget version
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Bump version
        uses: SiqiLu/dotnet-bump-version@master
        with:
          version_file: "src/**/*.csproj"
          version_mask: "0.0.1.0"
          version_overwrite: "*.*.*.*"
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

And then finally when the .csproj file change is detected we publish the package. **Is there a way to only check if the version changed?**

```
name: Publish to GitHub Packages

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
    paths:
      - 'src/**/*.csproj'

jobs:
  publish:
    name: build, pack & publish
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Setup .NET
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
        with:
          dotnet-version: 7.0.x

      - name: Auth with Github
        run: dotnet nuget add source --username ahc-service --password ${{secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} --store-password-in-clear-text --name github "https://nuget.pkg.github.com/COMPANY/index.json"

      - name: Package project
        run: dotnet pack --configuration Release

      - name: publish
        run: dotnet nuget push "**/*.nupkg" --source "github"
```